# Ruby on Rails Error Using Rails Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have started learning Ruby On Rails. I have Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.1.1 on my Debian Linux. I was following the instructions here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation?view=asciicast
However, when I try to use the method `rails g scaffold product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets`. I get this error;

```
"/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000016b9058> (NoMethodError)
from /root/Desktop/RubyOnRails/store/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
from /root/Desktop/RubyOnRails/store/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Store>'
from /root/Desktop/RubyOnRails/store/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'"
```

I get the error, also when I try to generate a controller or model. Because of this error, I can not follow any tutorial. I have tried to reinstall Rails but did not work.How can I solve this? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I solved it by reinstalling Ruby and Rails again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling Ruby and Rails again

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
rails g scaffold product name price:decimal --no-stylesheets
```

instead --skip

You can do also in config/application.rb something like this.

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.stylesheets false
end
```

You can see more details here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators

Comment: Thank you. However, the error is not about the parameter but the command itself, even if I use without the parameter "rails g scaffold product name price:decimal" , does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

```
1. rails new demo

2. cd demo

3. rake db:create

4. rails g scaffold product name:string price:float

5. rake db:migrate

6. rails server
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'neo4j/railtie'
```

Comment: I added it, and installed the gem as well, however still the same result